# Cannot update multiple rows at once

Tags: php

I have this code which I use to update multiple rows at once, but it only makes me one update..

Could you please help me check it? I can't find anything wrong with it. Thanks!

The form:

```
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='att_id[$i]' value='{$rows['att_id']}' s/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='attivita_da_promuovere[$i]' value='{$rows['attivita_da_promuovere']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text'id='start_date' class='datepicker' title='D-MMM-YYYY' name='start_date[$i]' value='{$rows['start_date']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text'id='end_date' class='datepicker' title='D-MMM-YYYY' name='end_date[$i]' value='{$rows['end_date']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='attivita_tip_merc[$i]' value='{$rows['attivita_tip_merc']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='attivita_da_svolgere[$i]' value='{$rows['attivita_da_svolgere']}' /></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='attivita_tip_personale[$i]' value='{$rows['attivita_tip_personale']}' /></td>";
```

The query:

```
$id_job=$_GET['id'];
$size = count($_POST['att_id']);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
$attivita_da_promuovere= $_POST['attivita_da_promuovere'][$i];
$start_date= $_POST['start_date'][$i];
$end_date= $_POST['end_date'][$i];
$attivita_da_svolgere = $_POST['attivita_da_svolgere'][$i];
$attivita_tip_merc = $_POST['attivita_tip_merc'][$i];
$attivita_tip_personale=$_POST['attivita_tip_personale'][$i];
$id=$_POST['att_id'][$i];


$query = "UPDATE attivita SET attivita_da_promuovere = '$attivita_da_promuovere',attivita_da_svolgere = '$attivita_da_svolgere',attivita_tip_merc = '$attivita_tip_merc',end_date = '$end_date',attivita_tip_personale = '$attivita_tip_personale',start_date = '$start_date' WHERE att_id = '$id' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
++$i;
```

Comment: Just print out your `$query` and check what that query is trying to do, if you variables are passed.

Comment: Your update statement ends with `LIMIT 1`. That should be a clue

Comment: @Blerta Blerta when the update query is execute....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you said that your form is inside foreach function?
thats make sense.

first you need to initiate your form once.

ex (right way of doing):

```
<?php 
echo "<form method='post'>";
foreach(){
    // rows here
}
echo "</form>";
?>
```

maybe you doing it like this (the wrong way) :

```
<?php 
foreach(){
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    // rows here
    echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you giving `LIMIT 1` in query. Remove it like

```
$query = "UPDATE attivita 
SET attivita_da_promuovere = '$attivita_da_promuovere',
attivita_da_svolgere = '$attivita_da_svolgere',
attivita_tip_merc = '$attivita_tip_merc',
end_date = '$end_date',
attivita_tip_personale = '$attivita_tip_personale',
start_date = '$start_date' WHERE att_id = '$id'";
```

Comment: Can it maybe be because my form is inside a foreach function?

Answer (score 0):

IF it is only affecting one row the only thing you need to take a look at is your `WHERE`clause, what it is implying and why does it only get 1 row.

Also, you have a LIMIT 1 in your query, which in this case I understand is exactly the opposite of what you want, so remove it.

New query would be something like:

> $query = "UPDATE attivita SET attivita_da_promuovere =
>   '$attivita_da_promuovere',attivita_da_svolgere =
>   '$attivita_da_svolgere',attivita_tip_merc =
>   '$attivita_tip_merc',end_date = '$end_date',attivita_tip_personale =
>   '$attivita_tip_personale',start_date = '$start_date' WHERE att_id =
>   '$id'";

A small tip for that 'echo' block there, you can simply exit your php script with `?>`, then type your HTML and re-open your script with `<?php`

Comment: Can it maybe be because my form is inside a foreach function?

Comment: What would the foreach change? :P you can still exit your script there, type your HTML, reopen it, finish your loop. Its PHP, make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make a mistake here:

The names you put onto the page are

name=attivita_da_promuovere1

name=attivita_da_promuovere2

name=attivita_da_promuovere3
..

And you try to read the posts as an array with the name 'attivita_da_promuovere'($_POST['attivita_da_promuovere'][$i]). I can´t see how there could be such an array since you give them individual names.

Shouldn´t you read the posts as such?

```
$_POST['attivita_da_promuovere'.$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE attivita SET attivita_da_promuovere = '$attivita_da_promuovere',attivita_da_svolgere = '$attivita_da_svolgere',attivita_tip_merc = '$attivita_tip_merc',end_date = '$end_date',attivita_tip_personale = '$attivita_tip_personale',start_date = '$start_date' WHERE att_id = '$id'";
```

Try this code in your update